# remap evil-mode normal-state folding key to folding-mode folding-toggle-show-hide

Tags: evil, code-folding

Is there a way to **remap** the "zc" or "zf" key combo for code folding from evil-mode normal-state to folding-toggle-show-hide?

I tried 
`(define-key evil-normal-state-map "zc" 'folding-toggle-show-hide)` without success.

F1 k zc returns:

```
z c runs the command evil-close-fold, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in 'evil-commands.el'.

It is bound to z c.

(evil-close-fold)

Close fold at point.
See also 'evil-open-fold'.
```

Comment: "without success" is pretty generic.  What happens when you press `zc`? Do you get an error? Do you get nothing?  What does `F1 k zc` display?

Comment: I edited the question. The issue is that *zc* is mapped to `'evil-code-fold` and I would like to remap it. The above definition did not do any (re)mapping. I also tried to map a not mapped key combination `ff` to `'folding-toggle-show-hide' but it does not work.

Comment: Where and at which point in time do you do the remapping?  Does it happen in your init file?  Does the remapping work if done *after* init?  You should be able to verify the latter by using `M-:` and the same expression as above.

Comment: The above mentioned `define-key` argument is the last line of the init file.

Comment: I managed to assign another key that was not occupied using `(define-key evil-normal-state-map "zt" 'folding-toggle-show-hide)`